# Designing for different screen sizes using ConstraintsLayouts

Tags: java, android, ios, screen-size, android-constraintlayout

I have started to dive into the Constraints Layout that were announced on the IO this year. This looks very promising and makes your layouts very efficient. I have seen the codelab excersize provided by Google. However I have the following questions that I would like to resolve.

1. How can *ConstraintLayouts* be used to design the layout for different screen sizes?

Currently I design the layout and set the views' margins and paddings etc for a specific device/screen group. Save those values in the `dimens.xml` file. This is a REALLY painful method to design the layouts. Does the Android *ConstraintsLayout* mimic the *AutoConstraintsLayout* of iOS in designing for multiple screens as well?

2. Does designing the Layout for different screen orientation still need different Layout.xml files i-e; *layout_landscape.xml* and *layout_portraint.xml*?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the entire point of ConstraintLayout (and for that matters, any Android layout since Android 1.0) is to be able to handle different screens (dimension, density...). You have nothing special to do (other than specifying constraints between widgets).

If you want to design for different screen sizes, think about margins as "minimum" spacing; and create constraint between widgets so that you position widget relative to other widgets.

You also have guidelines and bias centering, which give you a lot of flexibility.

Regarding the screen orientation, it is entirely up to you -- if you do nothing, the layout you define will be applied on either orientation. So, it would "work". But often, you want a *different* UI between portrait and landscape. In that case, you can indeed create two layout files, and the usual system will pick the right one for you.

Finally, you can easily test how the layout you are working on would behave in a different screen/device by changing the current screen definition from the popup in Android Studio:

[image: Screeen popup]

You can also use the resize handle to see the layout to an arbitrary screen dimension.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question regarding should we have to find the dimensions of each view by trail and error on each device in Android studio or we just have to define the constraints like XCode allows us?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are asking -- the views dimensions may change (language, theme..), but that's why you would use the constraints to position the views relative to one other, yes.

Comment: @NicolasRoard all devices doesnt come in same DP size. i.e. nexus S is less than 360 dp while pixel XL is greater than 500 dp. so using constrain layout if you arrange margin and padding for nexus S so that layout fits the screen perfectly then same layout will have additional space below in pixel XL and vise-versa. So yes either we have to create value-sw360dp, value-sw400dp, value-sw450dp and so on and place dimens.xml in each with proper scaled value OR i am missing an obvious simple solution which is what OP is asking also.

Comment: @NicolasRoard interestingly i found the chains and guidelines to overcome the problem i am facing, well for the most part atleast.

Answer (score 1):

> How can ConstraintLayouts be used to design the layout for different
>   screen sizes?

If by different screens you mean phone and tablets then you have to create different layout for them. one way to do it is to define `layout-sw360dp`,`layout-sw600dp` and `layout-sw720dp`.

> Currently I design the layout and set the views' margins and paddings
>   etc for a specific device/screen group. Save those values in the
>   dimens.xml file.

You might wanna look into [chains and guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain).

> Does designing the Layout for different screen orientation still need
>   different Layout.xml files i-e; layout_landscape.xml and
>   layout_portraint.xml?

Yes.