# Designing for different screen sizes and orientation using ConstraintsLayouts

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In addition to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433967/designing-for-different-screen-sizes-using-constraintslayouts), what's the best approach on creating layouts for different screen sizes AND orientation?

1. layout-land and layout-port and 1 layout using ConstraintLayout
   to    fit both phones and tablets
2. layout-sw360, layout-640 etc for different group of devices (ie tablets and smartphones)
3. layout-land, layout-port, layout-sw360, layout-640, to be more precise for every device
4. item 1. or 2. using ConstraintPercent and Guidelines and creating dimens qualifiers files (dimens-sw360, dimens-land, etc)

Comment: There is no general recipe. It depends very much on the items in the screen. Some assemblies work in all sizes and orientations, with others you need a separate specification for each.

Comment: You'll have to figure this out by trial and error because it is opinion based and depends on the UI you are trying to make.